# android studio Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java

Tags: java, android, gradle, message

[image from android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAV3x.png)

what can i do with this error message?

```
Information:31-07-2016 10:26 - Compilation completed with 15 errors and 0 warnings in 12s 4ms
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.loadDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:79)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:136)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-freetype-sources.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:336)
```

Comment: any solution u found ?

Comment: MY JOKES PROJECT IT WAS VERY BIG I REMOVE SOME JOKES THEN HE WORK WELL